# Serverless: How to remove/deploy deployment without .serverless directory for team collaboration

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

How do I remove/deploy deployment without .serverless directory for team collaboration?

For example if I run `sls deploy --aws-profile profile1` with a .yml file it then creates this .serverless directory which I am not including in my git push to hide secrets. Now when someone else clones this repo on my team how can they now manage the same deployment? Is the .yml file and same aws profile sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .serverless folder is created by serverless to alocate the cloud formation files. You should not handle them manually (and the folder and it’s content should not be included in source control).

The serverless.yml is the source of truth for the deployment, so it should do the same if running with the same environments.

The AWS account/profile can be set using the AWS cli. Given all the devs use the same account or use accounts with the same level of permissions, each one of you should be able to run deploy/remove.

If you project uses a .env file or environmental variables, each member of the team has to include them in their environment.